# Subset groups which contain several specific values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df such as

df

```
Groups COL1
G1 A
G1 B
G1 C
G3 D
G3 E
G4 A
G5 A
G5 B
G6 B
G6 B
```

and I would like to subset only Groups which contain A AND B, here in the example:

outputdf:

```
Groups COL1
G1 A
G1 B
G1 C
G5 A
G5 B
```

I tried:

```r
outputdf<- df%>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  filter(any(COL1=="A") & any(COL1="B"))
```

Comment: Doesn't your code give you the wanted output? Just replace `COL1="B"` with `COL1=="B"`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `all` with `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Groups) %>% 
   filter(all(c("A", "B") %in% COL1))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   Groups [2]
#  Groups COL1 
#  <chr>  <chr>
#1 G1     A    
#2 G1     B    
#3 G1     C    
#4 G5     A    
#5 G5     B
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G4", 
"G5", "G5", "G6", "G6"), COL1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```